# How to implement catching and showing the current key presses using a WPF TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Like the one in `Visual Studio > Options > Keyboard > Press shortcut keys field`.

Can I save this key press as a single combined value, or do I have to save the key press and each modifier key separately?

I just wanna show the currently pressed keys in the `TextBox` like:

```
Ctrl+G
Alt+X
Shift+V
R
Ctrl+Alt+S
etc
```

Also looking for the best way to store the keypress value. If I have to store the keys and modifier keys separately, then I will make a new type that has all of them in one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the textbox KeyDown event:

```
        string keys = "";

        if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) > 0)
        {
            keys += "Control + ";
        }

        if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) > 0)
        {
            keys += "Alt + ";
        }

        if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) > 0)
        {
            keys += "Shift + ";
        }

        keys += e.Key;

        YourTextBox.Text = keys;
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but if I press "Alt + anyKey", it prints "Alt + System", and not say "Alt + F". How to correct this behaviour?

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_key) you will find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any quicker way than what Navid is showing (check for each Modifier individually).

In addition, there is no built-in type that combines the Key and Keyboard.Modifiers already, so you will have to create your own like this:

```
public class KeyboardStatus
{
    public KeyboardStatus(Key key, ModifierKeys modifiers)
    {
        _modifiers = modifiers;
    }

    public Key PressedKey { get; set; }
    public bool IsControlPressed { get { return ((_modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) > 0); } }
    // ....

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string display = string.Empty;

        display += ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) > 0) ? "Ctrl + " : string.Empty;
        display += ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) > 0) ? "Alt + " : string.Empty;
        display += ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) > 0) ? "Shift + " : string.Empty;
        display += ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Windows) > 0) ? "Win + " : string.Empty;
        display += PressedKey.ToString();
        return display;
    }
    ModifierKeys _modifiers;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but if I press "Alt + anyKey", it prints "Alt + System", and not say "Alt + F". How to correct this behaviour?

Comment: Could it be that the line display += Key.ToString() is actually using Key as the type rather than Key the local property? Try renaming the Property to PressedKey (or some other non-reserved name). I'll change the example.